# How to assign data to a variable from a GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I am trying to pass an ID to the API and have the server return the object and then assign that object to a variable but I cant quite figure out where I am going wrong

```
        function createList() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 ){
                var theList = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log("the name of the current list given the ID is: " + theList.name);
            }
        };

        xhttp.open('GET', 'todoapi/lists/' + editID , true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

I want the end result to be a variable that is storing an object, obtained by passing the API the object's id

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: what is currently happening when you try?

Comment: @ZeyadEtman I am trying to pass my API an ID for a list that is already on the server, and then assign the list being returned to "theList" variable

Comment: @ADyson I am getting a status code: 404 that nothing is found in the database with the ID I am passing

Comment: Do you have the server side code?

Comment: @hemel no, but i have the REST urls

Comment: `I cant quite figure out where I am going wrong` - Developer Tools, Network Tab

Comment: @James I can see that I am getting a status code: 404, but I dont know why. The server is not returning the list when i give it the the lists ID

Comment: Does your constructed URL in the network tab look like what it should to hit the API?  If you right click the request and hit "open in new tab" it will show you the full url and you can check it that way.

Comment: Your status is 404 then `this.status == 200` will become `false`. Just show your error message what has been appeared in you `Console` tab of Developer tool.

Comment: You'll get a 404 either because the ID you've supplied doesn't exist in the database, or because your URL is just plain wrong. Check your browser's network tab to see if the URL is what you expected. We can't check that for you, and we also have no info about your server to be able to verify whether you specified the URL correctly to begin with

Comment: It ended up being a URL problem, i found it once i checked to network tab. thank you!